# SQL Server Agent job - write to application log as error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, event-log, sql-server-agent, sql-job

When my SQL Job fails I have a notification "Write to the Windows Application event log: When the job fails". This works fine, just that it's wrote with Level warning. Is it possible to write it as Error? Or do I have to set up an Alert for that?